# mySqli Error when I put the 'mysqli_connect' and the 'mysqli_query' in different pages

Tags: php, mysqli

why when i put the 'source 1' in one page and the 'source 2' in another page ( and use 'include()' ), its not work for me?

but when i put the 'source 1' and the 'source 2' in the same page, it works fine.

i check it and the call to 'include()' is fine. the include open fine the page that 'source 1' is in.

**source 1:**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","talkbox") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

**source 2:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $element[0] ($element[1]) VALUES ($element[2])";
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Eror: ' . mysqli_error($link));     // this is line 57. here i have the eror.
```

**this is the eror that i see:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\my portable
>   files\TDB\manager.php on line 57
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\my
>   portable files\TDB\manager.php on line 57
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\my portable
>   files\TDB\manager.php on line 57
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\my
>   portable files\TDB\manager.php on line 57 Eror:

**edit:**

i put the 'source 2' in function. i see that when i  didnt put it in a function, the source work good. so i think that i know how to solve this.

this is the full source of the 'source 2':

```
include("config.php");

function ab() {
    $query = "INSERT INTO mem (nic, email) VALUES ('aa','xx')";
    mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Eror: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}

ab();
```

the 'source 1' is in config.php

**edit:
thank you all, i solve the problem!**

Comment: So you have `<?php include(source1); mysqli_query($link, ...); ?>` ? Because your errors keep stating that $link doesn't actually exist.

Comment: show the code for include. the only possible case I can think of is if you are including HTTP pages, not php files

Comment: Also, your queries are essentially insecure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to save the connection in global variable:

```
$GLOBALS['link'] = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","talkbox") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Then you can access it anywhere in your script. The reason for the error you get might be that the variable `$link` is out of scope.

Comment: unfortunately, you don't quite understand what this $GLOBALS array after.

Comment: can you elaborate on that, please? I'm using this in my own scripts and it works, so I'd like to know what's wrong with that

Comment: Surely it works, as it does not harm. But if you make it just `$link = mysqli_connect` it will be working as well (unless you are connecting in a function but in such a case you have to return link instead of making it global).